# android studio 3.0 recording video is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, video-recording

I trying to record video on my emulator. I can see the record option in logcat tab and it records but the file saved is not in mp4 and it do not open. How to fix this issue? 
I am trying on emulator. Is there any restriction on the resolution for recording video

Comment: Any error information? 1. Did you definitely chosen mp4 format? 2. You can not save file to some locations like desktop/ folders on desktop/ direct folders under disk C: (users, even program files may not work), you must save it somewhere deeper 3. There is no restriction, though resolution must be multiple of 16px (which end up in something like 1920x1088 instead of 1080)

Answer (score 3):

Try command line

Start recording:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/video.mp4
```

Stop Recording
Ctrl-C

Save on PC

```
adb pull /sdcard/video.mp4 video.mp4
```

Comment: This worked great - I was led astray by android docs ( https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video ) which if I try their instructions it only saves in 'webm' format - there is no "mp4" option.

Comment: Yes.. there should be an option to export as MP4 untill webm adopted widely. While going to edit the video in iMovie, it fails to recognize format. Converting the video to mp4 is additional work IMO.

Comment: Below error I am getting while try to records video from above command

/system/bin/sh: screenrecord: inaccessible or not found

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the AS video recording will save the video without a file extension, even though it is a valid file. In this case, you can add the .mp4 file extension to the file name when you save it, which will allow you to open and view it after. This has worked for me before.